# New Badge Idea : Baffling badge

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badge-request

A question with 100 views without an answer should earn you the baffling badge. It means that no one who read your question was able to answer it.

It wouldn't apply to closed questions, of course.

It's almost the same as a bounty... some people might be compelled to try to find an answer to the question by challenge.

Comment: I think it's a lot more likely that if 100 people read your question and nobody answered it, then your question sucked.  Most people don't even bother to open questions that look too obscure; if 100 people opened it and couldn't answer then either your title was misleading or your question was too poorly-written to make sense of.  So, no thanks, we don't need this badge, Tumbleweed is plenty.

Comment: That's `badge`, not `gadge` in the title, unless you are trying to be `baffling` with your spelling ;)

Comment: @Peter : Corrected.

Comment: +1 from me.  I think that this is probably a bad idea however, I **don't think that we should downvote innocent and potentially helpful suggestions**

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude: we downvote bad ideas.  That's what Meta does.  Nothing personal.

Comment: @Michael, fair enough.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think such a badge would be encouraging the wrong thing.  Wouldn't it be better to give a badge to the person who *answers* a baffling question?  Maybe we could give a badge for accepted answers to questions that previously won a [Tumbleweed](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/63/tumbleweed).

Comment: this is a much better idea

Comment: Or which qualified for a Tumbleweed, anyway.  I've already got mine (and come to the conclusion that almost nobody on SO has any expertise in U3D), and may ask an obscure question again sometime.

Comment: ...and it could be called Bushwhacker.

Comment: [Tumble]weed-smoker?

Comment: @Jon, I think [Tumble]weedkiller would be better.

Comment: A killer of weeds? The only sensible badge name is [Monsanto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsanto). ;)

Comment: @gnovice: How about Roundup?

Comment: Thanks for perfecting my idea. I wanted something like that.

Comment: Isn't that what the `Necromancer` badge is meant for?

Comment: @Filburt: Close, but not quite.  `Necromancer` is awarded for answering any question that's more than 60 days old and getting 5 upvotes.  This would be targeting a smaller set of questions, those that aren't getting any attention at all.

Answer (score 1):

I lifted most of this answer from my [answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57272/how-can-i-attract-the-experts-to-answer-my-very-specific-question)

> Basically the best way to look at each question is "why should they care?"
>
> 1. It's easy. Low effort to solve.
> 2. It's really difficult. Hard effort to solve. (some people love pain)
> 3. It's high visibility. Lots of rep involved.
> 4. You're clueless. Some people love to help.
> 5. It's an interesting problem.

Basically, for a question to get to 100 views without a single answer, it means that it failed *or muddled* these five criteria.

If you have not created a *reason* for people to answer, then they won't.

I don't see why we would offer a reward for creating a fundamentally confused/indecipherable question.

Comment: Sadly, this seems to mean that uninteresting medium difficulty questions, asked by someone with a clue, are most likely to get unanswered.  Hmm.  True perhaps, but not ideal.

Comment: @beska Well, "uninteresting" questions are going to have a hard time getting answered anyway. Maybe you should try opening with a joke. Actually don't, SO won't appreciate.

Comment: Yep.  I think it's one of those things.  I guess that's what bounties are for, right?

Answer (score 1):

On first glance I think that this is a terrible idea, but what if we changed the requirements a bit?  What if we said something along the lines of:

> A question with 100 views without an answer should earn you the baffling badge. It means that no one who read your question was able to answer it.

The question must also have  more than 5 votes.

This would mean that the community thinks that the question is of interest and is valuable but cannot answer it.  If the question is closed because of being too specific ... then it will not get this badge.

Comment: That strangely looks like what I propose http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas/58379#58379, but I would also say that a time delay and an higher amount of view would be require for a such badge.