# Also suggest starting a bounty for old questions with zero answers

Tags: feature-request, bounties, unanswered-questions

To remain consistent with the

> Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?

for questions which have answers but none was accepted,

> Have you considered starting a bounty for this question?

should be displayed for 0-answers questions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57272/how-can-i-attract-the-experts-to-answer-my-very-specific-question/57319#57319)

> Assuming that you have already done the following:
>
> 1. Re-evaluated the question to see if it could be made clearer.
> 2. Re-evaluated the question to see if it could be made shorter.
> 3. <strike>Engaged with any responses or comments and edited to incorporate feedback.</strike> N/A this time.
> 4. Continued working on the problem on your own and updated the question with new information.
> 5. Considered a bounty.

Bounties are not meant to replace steps 1-4. In fact, if you haven't go through those earlier steps, then adding a bounty will likely not help at all. Adding a bounty on unanswerable questions will generate *bad* answers.

I think a better message would be.

> Have you considered any of the suggestions in the [Style Guidelines for Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18614/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers-on-stackoverflow)?

Comment: That's an even better message, I'll accept it in 5 minutes. Although I don't like the assumption that an unanswered question is really unanswerable.

Comment: Well, that's the point of my post. :) Unanswered doesn't mean unanswerable, but the onus is still on the OP to *improve* their post.

Comment: @Tobias. Also, take your time on the accept, see if better answers come along =D

Comment: the accept-check can be moved later on again in case a "correcter" answer shows up, or do questions with accepted answers really discourage others from posting useful answers? I stumbled upon some questions where the highest voted answer was posted after the accepted answer (although I'm not sure whether it was also *accepted* before the new answer showed up)

Comment: @Tobias It's an open question. No one really knows.